# C++ lambda function cause memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
  int AsyncUpdator::EnqueueTask(TaskInfo task_info) {
-    auto task = [=] {
-        this->DoTask(task_info);
-    };
+    auto task = std::bind(AsyncUpdator::DoTask, task_info);
    return 0;
}
```

```
    struct TaskInfo {
       GetRequest get_request; // this is a protobuffer structure
       uint64_t log_id;
   };
```

read lines causes the problem but the green lines doesn't?

Comment: _thread_pool is my async task runner

Comment: I just put the lambda function or bind function into the thread pool, and the red ones cause memory leak, but green ones doesnt. I don't know why

Comment: you should really type the code in the image as text here. other than that, what library is this? it's not standard library stuff. we don't know what these functions do, but you don't make any allocations in the provided lines. if i had to guess it would be because the lambda makes a copy of the object.

Comment: Yes, I have never made any allocations(like new), but memory leak happens

Comment: The lambda won't inherently cause a memory leak.  The functions it calls will.  From the minimal information you have provided, the culprit will be in `DoTask()`.   Without information about what that function does, nobody can help further.

Answer (score 1):

In the first option `auto task = [=] () {};` is capturing local variables as copies but `std::bind` captures your `task_info` as an rvalue reference and uses forwarding to pass it into your function as a reference.

If you don't want to use `std::bind` switch the lamba to capture by reference like `auto task = [&] () {};`.